# why "control" drag from a button to another screen fro a modal/push segues is deprecated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

when i control drag from a button to a view to create a segue i see this:

[image]

why is it deprecated and what is the modern alternative?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of the universal size classes you can add split view and stuff.
here's the whole scoop [a link]https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: The link you sent this is how i should create segues now?

Comment: Yeah Table #1 tells you what the new segues are..